# Can't run python script getting error urllib error 403

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can't run python script getting error urllib error 403.Can you help me please with this code. i can't find error. Worked good, but now it's not working.

```
import urllib
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import requests
import ssl
url = "https://www.proovl.com/api/send.php?"
params = {
'user': "1212",
'token': "121",
'from': "3333333",
'to': "444444444",
'text': "text"}
try:
    _create_unverified_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    ssl._create_default_https_context = _create_unverified_https_context
query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
http_req = url + query_string
f = urllib.request.urlopen(http_req)
freq = (f.read().decode('utf-8'))
x = freq.split(";")
g = x[1].replace("\"","")
y = x[0].replace("\"","")
if x[0] == "Error":
  print("Error message: ",x[1])
else:
  print("Message ID: ",x[1])
f.close()
```

error: is this problem with SSL?

```
    f = urllib.request.urlopen(http_req)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: 403 is an auth-error: https://httpstatuses.com/403. Is your `token` expired?

Comment: User and token combination is wrong. That's why Forbidden error

Comment: Yes. when i'm using right user and token i have same error 403. Prevues time with wrong token was error: wrong token or user
With right token and user same error

Comment: Thank you! problem was with headers. yes it's authorization. headers required
 `host = "https://www.proovl.com/api/send.php?"
    hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)' }` 
and 
`     req = urllib.request.Request(http_req, headers=hdr)
      f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)`